# getting error http://localhost:8800/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cors

i am getting `error http://localhost:8800/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`   my backend server working properly but problem when login on frontend on this URL which is

```
http://localhost:8800/login
```

in this url i am posting then i m getting this problem which is shown in this image

i am want solution to working problem you can gave me suggestion what i need to do this problem and how can i solve this problem

```js
//userroutes.js 

const express= require("express")
const router = express.Router();
const UserController = require("../controllers/UserController");

router.post("/login", UserController.Login);
router.post("/signup", UserController.Register);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
//usercontroller.js

const Usermodel = require("../models/UserSchema");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const Users = [];
const Register =async(req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
 
  if (data.email && data.password) {
    const hashedpassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
    try {
      const userExists = await Usermodel.findOne({
        email: data.email.toLowerCase(),
      });

      if (userExists) {
        res.send({ success: false, message: "User already exists" });
      } else {
        const newUser = await Usermodel.create({
          name: data.name,
          email: data.email.toLowerCase(),
          password: hashedpassword,
          phone: data.phone,
          address: data.address,
        });

        res.send({
          success: true,
          message: "Sign up successfully",
          data: newUser,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.send({ success: false, message: "Please fill in all data correctly" });
  }
};

//! login
const Login =async(req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;

  if (data.email && data.password) {
    try {
      const existUser = await Usermodel.findOne({
        email: data.email.toLowerCase(),
      });
      if (existUser) {
        const passwordMatch =  bcrypt.compare( data.password, existUser.password );
        if (passwordMatch) {
          const token = jwt.sign({ userId: existUser._id }, process.env.SECERET_KEY);
          res.send({ success: true, message: "login successfully ", token: token});
        } else {
          res.send({ success: false,   message: "please enter a valid password" })}
      } else {
        res.send({ success: false, message: "user not found " });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.send({ success: false, message: "please enter all fields" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  Register, Login
};
```

index.js, which is main file

```js
//! import npm
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const ConnectDB = require("./dbconfig");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/UserRoutes");
const taskRoutes = require("./routes/TaskRoutes");
ConnectDB();
//!.env
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT||8000;

//!use middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(taskRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Rather than `localhost`, have you tried `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: already solved problem

Comment: Then you could answer with the solution below, if you think it might help others.